# Why the return values of ReactDOM.render() are used in the unit tests of React repository?

Tags: reactjs

I read that using the return value of ReactDOM.render() is legacy and should be avoided because future versions of React may render components asynchronously in some cases at [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom.html#render).
However, I found this return values are used for testings in the official React source code repository.

- [https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/isomorphic/classic/element/**tests**/ReactElement-test.js#L352](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/isomorphic/classic/element/__tests__/ReactElement-test.js#L352)
- [https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/renderers/**tests**/ReactCompositeComponentState-test.js#L134](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/renderers/__tests__/ReactCompositeComponentState-test.js#L134)
- [https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/isomorphic/modern/class/**tests**/ReactPureComponent-test.js#L46](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/isomorphic/modern/class/__tests__/ReactPureComponent-test.js#L46)
- ...

There are many similar usages in test codes. I thought that [shallow rendering](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/test-utils.html#shallow-rendering) is recommendation to test React components after reading [this article](https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/whats-the-prefered-way-to-test-react-js-components/26). So, I wonder the return values of ReactDOM.render() are used in this test codes with special reasons.